# Swift - UITextField.text - error: string is not convertible to ()

Tags: swift

I'm taking a value from a UITextField object and am having difficulty using the UITextField.text property as a string. I'm trying to pass the value to a sanitizing function and attach the returned value to a variable but I can't get past the error **'String' is not convertible to '()'** and vice-versa. Even if I comment out the string sanitisation and simply return the value passed to the function I get the same problem. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cityName: UITextField!

    var city: String? = clean(cityName.text) // '()' is not convertible to 'String'

    if city != nil { /* Do Stuff... */ }


    func clean(str: String)
    {
        var trimmedStr = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        var cleanedStr = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-")

        return cleanedStr // 'String' is not convertible to '()'
        // return str produces same error
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set a return type for your clean function. It should look like;

```
func clean(str: String) -> String
```

Comment: Beauty, thanks. I knew it was something simple, I was reading Swift docs for Types not Functions so couldn't find what I needed..  Will mark as accepted in a few mins when SO lets me :)